# R - dplyr select() & filter()

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I'm a relatively new user of R and am trying to filter out relevant variables as well as ignoring `NA`s in order to make some graphics. As I use the `select()` function I get following error message:

> no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

The code I'm using is this:

```
select(year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: if the columns year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required are in a data frame you should call `select(your_dataframe, year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)` or `your_dataframe %>% select(year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)`

Comment: Can you post up your code and an example of your data, have you tried, can you use 'dput' of your dataframe

Comment: Considering your `year` object exists and is `numeric` I think there's a fair chance you misunderstood what `select` is for and you actually wanted `data.frame(year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)` or `tibble(year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)`

Comment: Adding the name of my dataframe worked. Thanks! I kind of get the select() function now.

Comment: Using the dput function works very poorly with my dataset. The dataset is very big and thus I did try to compress it before using the dput function. Still the outcome from using the dput() function is huge and make no sense since it contains data not included in the the compressed version. Also, reconstructing the data doesn't work. Any suggestions why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pipe operator - `%>%` to "push" your input data frame into `select` handler function of 'dlyr` package. Please see the simulation code below:

```
library(dplyr)

# data simulation
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  year = 2011:2018, 
  Total_US_received = (1:8) * 100, 
  Total_US_required = (1:8) * 50,
  no_need1 = rnorm(8),
  no_need2 = rnorm(8)
)

head(df)
#  year Total_US_received Total_US_required    no_need1   no_need2
# 1 2011               100                50 -0.56047565 -0.6868529
# 2 2012               200               100 -0.23017749 -0.4456620
# 3 2013               300               150  1.55870831  1.2240818
# 4 2014               400               200  0.07050839  0.3598138
# 5 2015               500               250  0.12928774  0.4007715
# 6 2016               600               300  1.71506499  0.1106827


# this is how select works in dplyr
df_out <- df %>% select(year, Total_US_received, Total_US_required)
head(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  year Total_US_received Total_US_required
1 2011               100                50
2 2012               200               100
3 2013               300               150
4 2014               400               200
5 2015               500               250
6 2016               600               300
```